# How to filter Inner Objects in Elasticsearch?

Tags: json, search, filter, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a `contacts` field in my documents in Elasticsearch. each element inside the `contacts` field is an Object itself. I want to use `term` or `terms` filter on `contacts` field so that it matches documents where `contacts.province_id` is `X`. I have tried `contacts.province_id` as search field but it doesn't work. How should I filter these kinds of fields?

```
"contacts": 
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "address": "address1",
     "tel": "40 07 13 22",
     "doctor_id": 1,
     "type_id": 1,
     "lng": "51.374720",
     "lat": "35.781986",
     "city_id": 186,
     "province_id": 8,
     "hour_about": null,
     "place_name": null
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "address": "address2",
     "tel": null,
     "doctor_id": 1,
     "type_id": 2,
     "lng": "51.520313",
     "lat": "35.726983",
     "city_id": 186,
     "province_id": 8,
     "hour_about": null,
     "place_name": null
  },
  {
     "id": 3,
     "address": "address3",
     "tel": null,
     "doctor_id": 1,
     "type_id": 2,
     "lng": "51.456368",
     "lat": "35.797505",
     "city_id": 186,
     "province_id": 8,
     "hour_about": null,
     "place_name": null
  }
]
```

**EDIT :**

I've tried this Query :

```
GET /index_name/type_name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "contacts.province_id": 8
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it returns **3** results, I expect **5** results. whats the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is each element in the array different documents ?

Comment: I think it should work the way you did it. The only mistake I see is that you performed a GET instead of a POST when querying your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the mapping you have used? If you are using nested type then try using the [nested filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html).

```
    {
         "filter": {
                "nested": {
                                "path": "contacts",
                                "filter": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "contacts.province_id": 3
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                   }
```